# How to make resizable TextField?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to make TextField resizable vertically and I have one idea about that

```dart
Expanded(
    child: TextField(
        cursorColor: Colors.black,
        decoration: new InputDecoration.collapsed(
//                                      border: new OutlineInputBorder(
//                                          borderSide: new BorderSide(color: hexToColor('#5c6277'),style: BorderStyle())
//                                      ),
            hintText: "El Baraka",hintStyle: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'RobotoLight',color: Colors.grey,fontSize: 16),
    ),
),
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved with `maxLines: null`:

```
TextField(
  cursorColor: Colors.black,
  decoration: new InputDecoration.collapsed(
    hintText: "El Baraka",hintStyle: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'RobotoLight',color: Colors.grey,fontSize: 16),
  ),
  maxLines: null,
)
```

Now `TextField` will add a new line when your text reaches the edge.